# MySQL の起動を確認するには？

Tags: mysql, macos

MySQL の起動の確認はどのようにしたらいいですか？

ダウンロードはターミナルから homebrew bash を用いました

またパッケージ MAMPもオフィシャルからインストールしました

Comment: 利用している環境(OSや利用しているソフトウェアmapp等々)やインストール方法(yumなどのパッケージ管理ツールを利用したのか等々)情報も追記してください

Comment: 直近の別質問にもコメントしましたが、2つ入れるのはトラブルの元なのでどちらか一方に的を絞った質問にして下さい。

Comment: 「macOSのローカルにhomebrewを使ってMySQLをインストールしたが、起動・常駐しているかどうかが分からないため確認したい」、ということでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

サーバに直接ログインできる管理者ならばMySQLの起動状況を確認する方法はいくつかあります。

- ターミナルから`mysql.server status`を実行する(Homebrewインストールした場合)

  - [【MacOS - Homebrew版】MySQLの設定方法（インストール→MySQLサーバー立ち上げ→パスワード設定等）](https://qiita.com/miketa_webprgr/items/ba7210ac57e2086fc5b6#c-mysql%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E7%8A%B6%E6%85%8B%E3%82%92%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)
- ターミナルから[`mysqladmin status`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/mysqladmin.html)を実行する(OS問わず)
- 「コントロールパネル」-「システムとメンテナンス」-「管理ツール」-「サービス」からMySQLの状態が「実行中」か確認する(Windows)

  - [MySQLサービスの開始と停止 - Windows環境](https://webkaru.net/mysql/windows-service-start-stop/)
- [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)にブラウザからアクセスし「状態」タブから起動状況を確認する(phpMyAdminインストール済の場合)

  - [phpMyAdmin の赤い警告もこれで怖くない！MySQL 状態変数の徹底ガイド](https://www.infiniteloop.co.jp/blog/2017/03/phpmyadmin-status-variables/)
  - [MAMPからphpMyAdminをブラウザに表示するまで](https://qiita.com/mako0104/items/cb677d04922a3d9672ae)
- レンタルサーバやクラウドサービスの管理者向けWebサイトから起動確認(外部サービス利用の場合)

  - サーバやサービスの種類によって確認画面の有無や確認方法が異なる